# asLongAs custom condition

Tags: scala, gatling

I am running a test, which has n users joining an event. To stay in the event each user must keep sending a websocket message every m seconds. This must be done until the last user is executing. I tried using asLongAs() but I am struggling on its usage. My simple condition was to increment a counter everytime the scenario executes, and keep a check on this number and keep sending the websocket message until the counter reaches the number of users.
How can I use the asLongAs method, or if there is a better approach than this.

P.S. I am new to scala.

EDIT::
I already have a global variable which has the number of total users. 
I want to do something on the lines of ::

```
asLongAs(scenarioCount< users){
  exec(
    ws("ping").sendText("SomeTextGoesHere"))
    .pause(4)
}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: EDIT::
I already have a global variable which has the number of total users. 
I want to do something on the lines of ::

    asLongAs(scenarioCount< users){
      exec(
        ws("ping").sendText("SomeTextGoesHere"))
        .pause(4)
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a global counter, you have to take care of concurrency.

```
val counter = new AtomicInteger(n)

asLongAs(session => counter.get) {
  ...
}
```

If you have multiple concurrent "events", you'll probably want to have to concurrent map in order to keep track of the counter for each event.